# Add to existing alias

Tags: bash, alias

The relevant part of my bashrc looks something like this:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    alias ls='ls --color=auto --list-directories-first' # use colors
    # ...
else
    alias ls='ls --list-directories-first' # don't use colors
    # ...
fi
```

This is to allow parts of the alias (specifically, whether to output colors) to be dynamically determined. But rewriting the entire alias each time is tedious to maintain, and I'd rather add to that alias than replace it entirely, so I'd like to have something like this:

```
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    alias ls='ls --color=auto' # use color output
    # ...
fi
alias ls='ls --list-directories-first' # 
# ...
```

But the later `alias ls=...` statement replaces the old alias. Is there a way to modify or gradually build the alias instead of replacing it?

Comment: `usecolors=; [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ] && usecolors='--color=auto'; alias ls="ls --list-directories-first $usecolors"`

Comment: As far as I know `ls` has no `--list-directories-first` option. But there is `--group-directories-first`.

Comment: @Sergio yeah I was writing from memory, that's probably the one I meant

Comment: Somewhat tangential, but why do you require `dircolors` to be present to use `--color`?

Comment: @chepner I haven't actually looked into whether it's necessary, but that's a leftover bit from the `.bashrc` that zsh generated automatically, and I figured that there was a reason. Probably not the best justification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[David said this concisely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50312297/add-to-existing-alias#comment87640988_50312297), but consider using a variable and building up your alias that way. For your specific case, just define a variable like `USE_COLORS` that starts as the null string:

```
USE_COLORS=
[ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ] && USE_COLORS='--color=auto'
alias ls="ls --list-directories-first $USE_COLORS"
```

You can also build up a variable command one part at a time:

```
LS_ALIAS='ls'
LS_ALIAS+='--list-directories-first'
[ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ] && LS_ALIAS+='--color-auto'
```